# Counting number of cells based on the month within cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to count the number of cells depending on the month in the cells on a different worksheet. I currently have the formula

```
=SUM(IF(MONTH('2022-23'!I2:I376)=1,1))
```

which is showing a #Value error.

Any ideas or solutions?

Comment: Can't replicate unless your data isn't actually numeric. Are you working with text looking like dates? If so, try `=SUM(N(MONTH(--'2022-23'!I2:I376)=1))`

Comment: I still get the error. The cells it is trying to reference has the short date format so it should be okay reading it.

Comment: I'm still doubtfull if they are actually dates.

Comment: They are all in the date format for example 04/01/2022

Comment: With actual dates you won't have an error. Can't think of any other reason why you still recieve errors. Have you checked each line? Even a single cell in the range that does not hold an actual date will make your formula return an error. Use the evaluate function that's build-in and pay close attention to what the array says when it evaluates `MONTH(.....)`

Comment: Ive managed to get it working. For some reason, although the header was not in my range to search for, I changed the header from a date format to a text format and it worked.